# jquery showing content if an element has a class and specific value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a navigation bar and would like to include an icon next to each element only if the element has a class of `"active"` and the value of the element is equal to a string.

http://gyazo.com/4811bc6779aaecd1fe80c020a69f1fb6.png

So, I have the icons next to the elements already, I don't want them to be visable until they have an active class like `Home` does. I tried this:

```
if($('.navbar-nav li').hasClass('active') && $('.navbar-nav li a').val() === "Home"){
    $('.navbar-nav li.active a').prepend('test ');
}
```

but it didn't work. I have different icons for each element so I'm guessing `elseif` for each case.

Markup for the navigation (displayed with PHP):

```
    <?php
      $nav = array(
     'Home' => 'index.php',
     '<span class="icon-bubbles"></span> Forums' => '#',
     '<span class="icon-cabinet"></span> Gametypes' => 'index.php?action=gamemodes',
     '<span class="icon-aid"></span> Help' => 'index.php?action=help',
     'Statistics' => 'index.php?action=statistics'
     );
    ?>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <?php
        $request = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        foreach($nav as $name => $link):
    ?>
    <li <?php if($request == $link) echo 'class="active"'; ?>><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $name ?></a></li>
    <?php
        endforeach;
    ?>
  <li>
    <a href="http://google.com" title="Thanks for voting!" rel="shadowbox[vote];width=1000px;"><span class="icon-pencil"></span> Minecraft Voting</a>
    <div style="display:none;">
        <a href="http://google.com" title="Thanks for voting!" rel="shadowbox[vote];width=1000px;"></a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` will not work. It works on input types. Use `.text()`

Try:

```
if($('.navbar-nav li').hasClass('active') && $('.navbar-nav li a').text() === "Home"){
    $('.navbar-nav li.active a').prepend('test ');
}
```

Comment: It looked like it was going to work but it didn't. Nothing changes

Comment: @davidxd33 it would be easier to understand if you provide HTML markup

Comment: It's not static html displaying the navigation. It's PHP however, I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($('.navbar-nav li').attr(class).indexOf('active')!=-1 && $('.navbar-nav li a').val() === "Home"){
    $('.navbar-nav li.active a').prepend('test ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.navbar-nav li.active a:contains(Home)').prepend('test ');
```

if the selector doesn't match any elements, nothing happens.